# ¿Por qué snowboy me da el error "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, debian-9

Esto es el código que uso y el problema que me da:

```
$  cd /rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1
root@rpi3: /rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1
$ python3 demo.py resources/models/hermes.pmdl

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import snowboydecoder   File "/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/snowboydecoder.py", line 5, in <module>
    import snowboydetect   File "/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/snowboydetect.py", line 28, in <module>
    _snowboydetect = swig_import_helper()   File "/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/snowboydetect.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_snowboydetect', fp, pathname, description)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: /rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/_snowboydetect.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tengo todo los documentos que me sirven para hacerlo funcionar
pero lo que no  entiendo es este error:

> ```
> ImportError: /rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/_snowboydetect.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```

Esta es la carpeta donde tengo todo:

[image: carpeta]

Comment: ¿Existe `/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/_snowboydetect.so`?

Answer (score 0):

Tu `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` no incluye la ruta de `_snowboydetect.so`. Tendrías que añadirla:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH me dice command not found

Comment: ¿Estás escribiendo bien el comando?

Comment: el tuyo si  lo copie i lo pege